# How do you make text input borders overlap?

Tags: css

```css
div input:not(:first-of-type){
    display: block;
}
#left_side{
    width: 40%
}
label{
    width:15em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
input{
    width: 23em;
    border-style:solid;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.group div{
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.group input {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.get{
    width:23em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <div>
        <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first_name" class="get">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="last_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="last_name" class="get">
    </div>
</div>

    <!--Here is some code with grouped boxes:-->

<div>
    <label for="address_1_ln_1">Address 1:</label>
    <div class="get">
        <input type="text" id="address_1_ln_1">
        <input type="text" id="address_1_ln_2">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="address_2_ln_1">Address 2:</label>
    <div class="get">
        <input type="text" id="address_1_ln_1">
        <input type="text" id="address_2_ln_2">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="city">City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" class="get">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="state">State:</label>
    <input type="text" id="state" class="get">
</div>
<dive>
    <label for="zip">Zip:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip" class="get">
</dive>
```

How do you make text input of forms overlap borders like `border: collapse` on a table? By default stacking them one on top of the other has them develop a 2px border between adjacent inputs. Ideally both the borders should merge.

[image: Overlapping image borders]

Comment: Remove one of the adjacent borders. If you supply your HTML, there's likely a generic CSS rule that could apply where necessary, but as it stands we can't really provide you with much without the markup.

Comment: Please write html code.

Comment: I added the html

Comment: What should happen if your text boxes don't align? For example, the only reason your inputs align perfectly in the screenshot (and example) is because you've given both inputs the same label.

Comment: They don't have the same label. Their texts are the same but they both have different labels. The reason why they align is because i set the labels to a width and made everything `inline-block`

Comment: In your example, the width wouldn't matter because they both say `First Name:`. As readers, we have no idea about the widths or `inline-block` because you've elected to omit that from your question. It's for this reason that the requirement for a [minimal, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) exists. In any case, I would start with a a CSS rule like `div.group > div:not(:first-child) input { border-top: 0; }` and see if you can progress from there.

Comment: Note typo in final div. I left it in when I added snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
input {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```